# 302 url redirect to paypal home page

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We are using the PayPal AdaptivePayments SDK since a while,

Now, the same URL as before is redirecting the customer to the paypal homepage 50% of the time with a 302 temporary redirect.

https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=XXXXXXXXXX.

the code is mostly a copy past from the paypal sample

```
public override string CreateRedirectUrl(NameValueCollection parameters)
{

    ReceiverList receiverList = new ReceiverList();
    receiverList.receiver = new List<Receiver>();

    PayRequest request = new PayRequest();
    RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_CA");
    request.requestEnvelope = requestEnvelope;
    request.feesPayer = "PRIMARYRECEIVER";
    //request.feesPayer = "SECONDARYONLY";

    Receiver receiver1 = new Receiver();

    if (parameters["amount1"] != null && parameters["amount1"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        // Required) Amount to be paid to the receiver
        receiver1.amount = Convert.ToDecimal(parameters["amount1"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    if (parameters["mail1"] != null && parameters["mail1"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        // Receiver's email address. This address can be unregistered with
        // paypal.com. If so, a receiver cannot claim the payment until a PayPal
        // account is linked to the email address. The PayRequest must pass
        // either an email address or a phone number. Maximum length: 127 characters
        receiver1.email = parameters["mail1"];
    }

    //if (parameters["primaryReceiver1"] != null && parameters["primaryReceiver1"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    //{
    //    receiver1.primary = Convert.ToBoolean(parameters["primaryReceiver1"]);
    //}

    receiver1.primary = true;
    receiver1.invoiceId = parameters["invoiceId"];

    receiverList.receiver.Add(receiver1);

    Receiver receiver2 = new Receiver();

    if (parameters["amount2"] != null && parameters["amount2"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        // (Required) Amount to be paid to the receiver
        receiver2.amount = Convert.ToDecimal(parameters["amount2"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    if (parameters["mail2"] != null && parameters["mail2"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        // Receiver's email address. This address can be unregistered with
        // paypal.com. If so, a receiver cannot claim the payment until a PayPal
        // account is linked to the email address. The PayRequest must pass
        // either an email address or a phone number. Maximum length: 127 characters
        receiver2.email = parameters["mail2"];
    }

    //if (parameters["primaryReceiver2"] != null && parameters["primaryReceiver2"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    //{
    //    receiver2.primary = Convert.ToBoolean(parameters["primaryReceiver2"]);
    //}

    receiverList.receiver.Add(receiver2);

    ReceiverList receiverlst = new ReceiverList(receiverList.receiver);
    request.receiverList = receiverlst;

    // (Optional) Sender's email address. Maximum length: 127 characters
    if (parameters["senderEmail"] != null && parameters["senderEmail"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        request.senderEmail = parameters["senderEmail"];
    }

    // The action for this request. Possible values are: PAY – Use this
    // option if you are not using the Pay request in combination with
    // ExecutePayment. CREATE – Use this option to set up the payment
    // instructions with SetPaymentOptions and then execute the payment at a
    // later time with the ExecutePayment. PAY_PRIMARY – For chained
    // payments only, specify this value to delay payments to the secondary
    // receivers; only the payment to the primary receiver is processed.
    //if (parameters["actionType"] != null && parameters["actionType"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    //{
    //    request.actionType = parameters["actionType"];
    //}
    request.actionType = "PAY";

    // URL to redirect the sender's browser to after canceling the approval
    // for a payment; it is always required but only used for payments that
    // require approval (explicit payments)
    if (parameters["cancelURL"] != null && parameters["cancelURL"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        request.cancelUrl = parameters["cancelURL"];
    }

    // The code for the currency in which the payment is made; you can
    // specify only one currency, regardless of the number of receivers
    if (parameters["currencyCode"] != null && parameters["currencyCode"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        request.currencyCode = parameters["currencyCode"];
    }

    // URL to redirect the sender's browser to after the sender has logged
    // into PayPal and approved a payment; it is always required but only
    // used if a payment requires explicit approval
    if (parameters["returnURL"] != null && parameters["returnURL"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        request.returnUrl = parameters["returnURL"];
    }

    request.requestEnvelope = requestEnvelope;

    // (Optional) The URL to which you want all IPN messages for this
    // payment to be sent. Maximum length: 1024 characters
    if (parameters["ipnNotificationURL"] != null && parameters["ipnNotificationURL"].Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        request.ipnNotificationUrl = parameters["ipnNotificationURL"];
    }

    AdaptivePaymentsService service = null;

    try
    {
        // Configuration map containing signature credentials and other required configuration.
        // For a full list of configuration parameters refer in wiki page
        // (https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/wiki/SDK-Configuration-Parameters)
        Dictionary<string, string> configurationMap = PaypalAdaptiveConfiguration.GetAcctAndConfig();

        // Creating service wrapper object to make an API call and loading
        // configuration map for your credentials and endpoint
        service = new AdaptivePaymentsService(configurationMap);

        Response = service.Pay(request);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
       // contextHttp.Response.Write(ex.Message);
        //return;
    }

    Dictionary<string, string> responseValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string redirectUrl = null;

    if (!Response.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals(AckCode.FAILURE.ToString()) && !Response.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals(AckCode.FAILUREWITHWARNING.ToString()))
    {
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAYPAL_MODE"].ToLower() == "live")
        {
            redirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAYPAL_REDIRECT_URL_LIVE"] + "_ap-payment&paykey=" + Response.payKey;
        }
        else
        {
            redirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAYPAL_REDIRECT_URL"] + "_ap-payment&paykey=" + Response.payKey;
        }
        // The pay key, which is a token you use in other Adaptive Payment APIs 
        // (such as the Refund Method) to identify this payment. 
        // The pay key is valid for 3 hours; the payment must be approved while the 
        // pay key is valid. 
        responseValues.Add("Pay Key", Response.payKey);

        // The status of the payment. Possible values are:
        // CREATED – The payment request was received; funds will be transferred once the payment is approved
        // COMPLETED – The payment was successful
        // INCOMPLETE – Some transfers succeeded and some failed for a parallel payment or, for a delayed chained payment, secondary receivers have not been paid
        // ERROR – The payment failed and all attempted transfers failed or all completed transfers were successfully reversed
        // REVERSALERROR – One or more transfers failed when attempting to reverse a payment
        // PROCESSING – The payment is in progress
        // PENDING – The payment is awaiting processing
        responseValues.Add("Payment Execution Status", Response.paymentExecStatus);

        if (Response.defaultFundingPlan != null && Response.defaultFundingPlan.senderFees != null)
        {
            // Fees to be paid by the sender
            responseValues.Add("Sender Fees", Response.defaultFundingPlan.senderFees.amount + Response.defaultFundingPlan.senderFees.code);
        }
    }

    foreach (ErrorData ed in Response.error)
    {
        this.ErrorMessage += ed.message + " ";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ErrorMessage))
    {
        new Tracker().sendToGenclikDev("PaypalAdaptiveGateway", this.ErrorMessage);
    }

    responseValues.Add("Acknowledgement", Response.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper());

        return redirectUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also had same issue but were able to fix it by making a small change.

You need to change the redirect URL:

**From this:**
https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=XXXXXXXXXX

**To:**
https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=XXXXXXXXXX

Note the "**?**" after 'webscr'.

Answer (score 1):

We are having exactly the same problem since Friday the 13th Jan 2017. It appears to mostly happen on the first payment redirect request. If you navigate back from the Paypal home screen, using the browser's back button and post again with a new token, it works.

Anybody that knows a solution would be of great help!

Comment: here the anwser from paypal : Our engineers are still looking into the issue. I will provide you an update as soon as one becomes available. Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: Do you have a link to the open issue on paypal? How can we follow up? Thanks